# Maximum possibility of banknotes to keep into the given integer value

Tags: c

Banknotes are given specifically 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1. Required to check and find out: What is the maximum possibility to keep these individually into the given integer value.
For example:

```
input: 576
output: 576
        5 nota(s) de R$ 100,00
        1 nota(s) de R$ 50,00
        1 nota(s) de R$ 20,00
        0 nota(s) de R$ 10,00
        1 nota(s) de R$ 5,00
        0 nota(s) de R$ 2,00
        1 nota(s) de R$ 1,00
```

I have solved this problem by following this strategy->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int number, count = 0, occupied = 0, number_update, i;
    int a = 100;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    number_update = number;
    printf("%d\n",number);

    //Getting the number that can be stored maximum in the given integer.
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        count = 0;

        while (a <= number_update){
        count++;
        occupied = occupied + a;
        number_update = number_update - a;
        }
        printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %d,00\n",count,a);
        number_update = number - occupied;

        if (i == 0){
         a = a-50;

        }

        else if (i == 1){
            a = a-30;
        }

        else if (i == 2){
            a = a-10;
        }

        else if (i == 3){
            a = a-5;
        }

        else if (i == 4){
            a = a-3;
        }

        else {
            a = a-1;
        }

       }
        return 0;
}
```

I am here for:
Would you propose any simplification from my existing solution?
Will I face any problem with some conditions?
The way I followed to solve this problem. Is it ok or not?

Comment: Sorry sir. I made a little mistake. 30 is not in that list. lists are 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't use the `for`-`case` antipattern

You are using the [`for`-`case` antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence), which you should almost always avoid. Instead, find some way to simplify your code. For example, instead of hardcoding the denominations in the `if`-statements, put them in an array:

```
static const int denominations[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
static const int n_denominations = sizeof denominations / sizeof *denominations;
```

Then use it like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_denominations; i++) {
    count = 0;

    while (number >= denominations[i]) {
        count++;
        number -= denominations[i];
    }

    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %d,00\n", count, denominations[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, sir, I am trying to follow this strategy from my next challenges. Thank you a ton for your worthy suggestions. Keep up the good works.